# Linux Bash: Moving/Copying files/directories by timestamp

Tags: linux, bash, debian, find, cp

This is the command I am using:

```
find absolute-path -name "*" -amin -120 -exec cp -f absolute-destination {} \;
```

I’m trying to copy a lot of directories from a directory to another directory, but only those created in the last 2 hours.

My command is not working though and I don’t really get why, if it’s not obvious I'm not a very experienced Linux user. From what I get `cp` seems to interpret my intended destination as the source.

I even tried using `xargs` and that I understand even less.

Using Bash in Debian Squeezy and running the command in root.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> From what I get `cp` seems to interpret my intended destination as the
>   source.

Yes, it is. That is because the general Linux/Unix syntax is something like this:

```
[some command] [some command options] [source item] [destination item]
```

So look at your command:

```
find absolute-path -name "*" -amin -120 -exec cp -f absolute-destination {} \;
```

That `cp -f absolute-destination {}` is backwards since the `{}` represents the source file as found by `find` command and the “absolute-destination” is exactly what it is; a destination. So that part of the command should be rewritten as `cp -f {} absolute-destination`.

Additionally:

- The `-name "*"` is redundant and superfluous if you are searching for all files based on time anyway; meaning you can just ditch that.
- Also, the use of `amin` is a bit confusing since `-amin -120` means “the file has been *accessed* in the last 120 minutes.” If you want to act on the *creation* time of files, yhat should be changed to `cmin`—aka: changed `n` minutes ago—instead; more details in the Linux [`find`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/find) man page.

So the final command would be:

```
find absolute-path -cmin -120 -exec cp -f {} absolute-destination \;
```

But before running that `cp` command you should always do a “dry run” using `echo` to see exactly what is happening like this:

```
find absolute-path -cmin -120 -exec echo {} \;
```

Remember, doing a test “dry run” of a command like this *before* running the actual/final command will save you headaches in the long run. Especially if you plan on running the command as `root`.

You never know if you might have made a simple, inadvertent mistake in your command logic that might screw up in unexpected ways. And rushing an errantly structured command into “production” without testing might save you a few minutes in the beginning but then could result in hours—and in some cases, days—of cleanup work. *Always* play it safe when working in the command line.